# How to define a variable for an entire project with multiple classes? c#

Tags: c#, global-variables

I have a project with multiple classes. For the script to run, I need to open an excel sheet to read it, and use the values from the sheet in my script. Currently I am having to open and read the excel sheet in each class. How can I define the variables such that I only need to open the excel sheet once and read all the values in at once? I need to be able to use these values in many different classes. Each class already inherits another class so I cannot use inheritance.

Comment: can you explain a little more, maybe share a bit of code?

Comment: Classes are the widest scope you can declare a variable in (you can't declare them in a namespace), so probably dependency injection is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use a static class with static variables

Create a static Public Class that contains your public globals variables
like this

```
public static class Globals
  {
 public static int mypublic_varible_1=0;
  }
```

Then you can create a method that assign value to your variable it will be another class.

```
public class assign_values{
   Globals.mypublic_varible_1=100;//data_read_from_excel

 }
```

Now your *Globals.mypublic_varible_1* have 100 as value because you can call it from another class.

Comment: it was incomplete, because i had problems with my keyboard, the enter key was locked

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is called dependency injection, which is where we can pass an object to a class that the class depends on. If we add constructors to our classes that take in an instance of the class that represents the excel document (i.e. it was populated by reading the document), then those classes can share the same document.

For example here's a simple class that represents what we read from the excel doc:

```
public class ExcelDocument
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"SomeValue: {SomeValue}, SomeOtherValue: {SomeOtherValue}";
    }
}
```

And here are two classes that take an instance of `ExcelDocument` in their constructors, and then manipulate values in it (for example):

```
public class ClassOne
{
    private ExcelDocument excelDoc;

    public ClassOne(ExcelDocument document)
    {
        excelDoc = document;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithExcelData()
    {
        excelDoc.SomeValue = "Modified in ClassOne";
    }
}

public class ClassTwo
{
    private ExcelDocument excelDoc;

    public ClassTwo(ExcelDocument document)
    {
        excelDoc = document;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithExcelData()
    {
        excelDoc.SomeOtherValue = "Modified in ClassTwo";
    }
}
```

Now, in our main program, we can read the document and populate our class (here I'm just setting the properties to "original value" instead of reading an actual document), and then we can pass the class to each of the two classes above so they can manipulate it:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        // "Read" an excel document and set properties in this class
        var excelDoc = new ExcelDocument
        {
            SomeValue = "original Value",
            SomeOtherValue = "original value"
        };

        // Instantiate the classes above so they can use the document without re-reading it
        var class1 = new ClassOne(excelDoc);
        var class2 = new ClassTwo(excelDoc);

        // Output the original values of our document
        Console.WriteLine(excelDoc);

        // Have each class do their operations on the document
        class1.DoSomethingWithExcelData();
        class2.DoSomethingWithExcelData();

        // Output the values again to show how the two independent classes 
        // manipulated the same document (and without reading it)
        Console.WriteLine(excelDoc);

        GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

---

Note that you also don't need to create classes that take the document as an argument to the constructor. You could instead create public methods on the classes that take in a document so they can use/manipulate the values. This way, you just "pass the document around" from class to class or method to method, without having to re-read the excel worksheet inside each class/method, for example you could have:

```
public class ClassOne
{
    public static void DoSomethingWithExcelData(ExcelDocument excelDoc)
    {
        excelDoc.SomeValue = "Modified in ClassOne";
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var excelDoc = new ExcelDocument
    {
        SomeValue = "original Value",
        SomeOtherValue = "original value"
    };

    ClassOne.DoSomethingWithExcelData(excelDoc);
```

Comment: A serious case of overkill.

Comment: @TaW how so?  Seems fairly simple to me.  Is there an easier way?